# How can I get the element or element itself from Event e

Tags: dart, dart-webui

How can I get the current LIElement's id which fire event e in activeNav(), because I want to find the active element from navMap.

```dart
import 'dart:html';

Map navMap = new Map<String, LIElement>();

void main() {
  navMap["#li-home"] =  query("#li-home");
  navMap["#li-about"] =  query("#li-about");
  navMap["#li-setting"] =  query("#li-setting");
  navMap["#li-home"].onClick.listen(activeNav);
  navMap["#li-about"].onClick.listen(activeNav);
  navMap["#li-setting"].onClick.listen(activeNav);
}

void activeNav(Event e){
  // Get element #li-home from map and add class "active"
  // remove the class "active" from remain LIElements in navMap
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to store all the `li` elements in a map. Just attach the event handler to the `ul` that contains the `li`s, figure out which `li` was clicked, and add or remove the 'active' class:

```dart
import 'dart:html';

void main() {
  query('ul').onClick.listen((event) {
    if (event.target.id == 'li-home') {
      event.target.classes.add('active');
    } else {
      event.target.classes.remove('active');
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Seem has error event.target.id has error "There is no such getter "id" in EventTarget".

Comment: Roger, I'm seeing the editor warnings as well. But the code runs correctly. The warnings don't make any sense. Using event.target gives you an LiElement object, and that definitely has an id.

Comment: You could use the `toggle` method to make the code more concise: `event.target.classes.toggle('active', event.target.id == 'li-home');`

Comment: To remove the warnings: from [this document](https://www.dartlang.org/codelabs/darrrt/#set-up): You should cast event.target to the element type you expect, like `(event.target as Element).classes.add('active')`